# Square-Connect 500 error when trying to delete batch of items

Tags: square-connect

Received 500 Internal Server Error executing POST of https://connect.squareup.com/v1/batch

with JSON object

{"requests":[

{"method":"DELETE",
   "relative_path":"/v1/me/items/13fd1363-2e1f-4b55-bfbf-f58b97814cfa",
   "access_token":"XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},

{"method":"DELETE",
   "relative_path":"/v1/me/items/9d415859-8758-4147-aa16-7088c84bb201",
   "access_token":"XXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"}

]}

When the same items are deleted individually there is no problem:

DELETE https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/items/13fd1363-2e1f-4b55-bfbf-f58b97814cfa

Also,  I have been able to execute inventory adjustments in batch so I think my technique is ok.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm amending the original post to include a sample response as suggested

```
[
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "0"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "1"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "2"
},
{
    "status_code": 500,
    "body": {
        "type": "internal_server_error",
        "message": "InternalServerError"
    },
    "request_id": "3"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "4"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "5"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "6"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "7"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "8"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "9"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "10"
},
{
    "status_code": 500,
    "body": {
        "type": "internal_server_error",
        "message": "InternalServerError"
    },
    "request_id": "11"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "12"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "13"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "14"
},
{
    "status_code": 500,
    "body": {
        "type": "internal_server_error",
        "message": "InternalServerError"
    },
    "request_id": "15"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "16"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "17"
},
{
    "status_code": 500,
    "body": {
        "type": "internal_server_error",
        "message": "InternalServerError"
    },
    "request_id": "18"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "19"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "20"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "21"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "22"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "23"
},
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "body": {},
    "request_id": "24"
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that we have fixed and the change now deployed.

Comment: We are still seeing a 500 response on a batch of deletes.  Previously, the  500 occurred on the first item in the batch.  Now it occurs somewhere after the first item.  We're also seeing an occasional 501 response on delete requests (which is not covered in your documentation).

Comment: Just to clarify,  previously the 500 occurred on the batch request itself,  and now the 500 is occurring on individual items in the batch.

Comment: Some more info to help you debug:  when the batch returns a 500 for a particular item,  I re-execute the delete standalone and receive a 404, indicating that the item was in fact deleted in the batch.  So the 500 is being issued after the delete succeeds.

Comment: Can you show some sample responses? I haven't been able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: I've just now added the sample response to the original post

Comment: This bug has resurfaced.  Maybe you should have a way of logging errors on the Square site instead of using Stackoverflow for all of you developer support?